# Strange Ubuntu boot up warning

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xen, xenserver, grub

I have a VM (Xen based), **I can boot** up the machine but there are some warning during the boot up.

Are they normal? If not, how to solved?

```
md: Scanned 0 and added 0 devices.                                                                                
md: autorun ...                                                                                                   
md: ... autorun DONE.                                                                                             
EXT3-fs: barriers not enabled                                                                                     
kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds                                                                    
EXT3-fs (xvda): mounted filesystem with writeback data mode                                                       
VFS: Mounted root (ext3 filesystem) readonly on device 202:0.                                                     
devtmpfs: mounted                                                                                                 
Freeing unused kernel memory: 688k freed                                                                          
Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 12288k                                                                
Freeing unused kernel memory: 560k freed                                                                          
Freeing unused kernel memory: 780k freed                                                                          
init: Failed to create pty - disabling logging for job                                                            
init: Temporary process spawn error: No space left on device                                                      
init: Failed to create pty - disabling logging for job                                                            
init: Temporary process spawn error: No space left on device                                                      
init: Failed to create pty - disabling logging for job                                                            
init: Temporary process spawn error: No space left on device                                                      
init: Failed to create pty - disabling logging for job                                                            
init: Temporary process spawn error: No space left on device                                                      
init: ureadahead main process (1331) terminated with status 5                                                     
init: Failed to create pty - disabling logging for job                                                            
init: Temporary process spawn error: No space left on device                                                      
init: Failed to create pty - disabling logging for job                                                            
init: Temporary process spawn error: No space left on device                                                      
init: Failed to create pty - disabling logging for job                                                            
init: Temporary process spawn error: No space left on device                                                      
FATAL: Module nf_conntrack_ftp not found.                                                                         
FATAL: Module nf_nat_ftp not found.                                                                               
FATAL: Module nf_conntrack_netbios_ns not found.                                                                  
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1                                                                                       
mountall: Disconnected from Plymouth                                                                              
/dev/xvda: clean, 195668/2653056 files, 1402362/6160384 blocks
```

When I run `df -h` after boot up, it is

df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda        24G  6.0G   17G  27% /
devtmpfs        493M  4.0K  493M   1% /dev
none             99M  180K   99M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            494M     0  494M   0% /run/shm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running out of space is never "ideal," and the solution is in the message itself.

> init: Failed to create pty - disabling logging for job
>   init: Temporary process spawn error: No space left on device

As the box can boot, run `df` and look for the disk near or at 100% utilization.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the result of `df` command.

Comment: This: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/980917 is likely what you're running into.  I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

If it is Ubuntu, you can ignore all of them.

```
"init: Failed to create pty - disabling logging for job"
```

This one is a known bug for Ubuntu 12.04

This one:

```
FATAL: Module nf_conntrack_ftp not found.                                                                         
FATAL: Module nf_nat_ftp not found.                                                                                
FATAL: Module nf_conntrack_netbios_ns not found.
```

I assume you are using custom Xen custom domU or similar kernel, 
To fix this you can remove uwf, recompile your kernel or adjust IPT_MODULES in /etc/default/ufw.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, yes I am using ufw, but seems it is functioning, why the error  or any drawback? I don't have control to update the kernerl as it is created by my hosting company.